# adding to a list of values in dictionary while iteration

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I was trying to count divisors of 10 numbers and add them as value to their dictionary but when I was trying to append other divisors to the list of values it didn't happen and got replaced. I wonder why this happens.

```
a = []
t = dict()
for i in range(10):
    a.append(input())
    a = [int(i) for i in a]
for num in a:
    for x in range (1, num + 1):
        if (num % x) == 0:
            t[num] = []
            t[num].append(x)
print(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you reinitialize `t[num]` when you should not:

```py
a = []
t = dict()
for i in range(10):
    a.append(input())
    a = [int(i) for i in a]
for num in a:
    for x in range (1, num + 1):
        if (num % x) == 0:
            if num not in t:  # Here: init t[num] to [] only if it does not yet exist
                t[num] = []
            t[num].append(x)

print(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can make your life easier here since it will take care if the list allocation.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = []
t = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(10):
    a.append(input())
    a = [int(i) for i in a]
for num in a:
    for x in range (1, num + 1):
        if (num % x) == 0:
            t[num].append(x)
print(t)
```